# find all subarrays in o(n) time 1D array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, kadanes-algorithm

I want to collect all subarrays for further computation efficiently in javascript. I'm not sure this is possible, but it seems for a subarray sum kadane's formula is o(n) which is more efficient than other methods. But I'm not sure I how I can store the array at each step.

Similar to this [quora question](https://www.quora.com/Can-we-find-the-sum-of-all-sub-arrays-of-an-integer-array-in-O-n-time), for me the pseudo code was not enough. Thanks for the further breakdown.

another [meta link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/256141/find-all-possible-subarrays-of-an-array)

an example in action of this for [3, 3, 9, 9, 5]

```
[3], [9], [5], [9, 5], [9, 3], [9, 9], [3, 3],
[3, 9, 9], [3, 3, 9], [9, 9, 5], [3, 3, 9, 9],
[3, 9, 9, 5], [3, 3, 9, 9, 5]
```

Comment: can you add some examples, what you mean?

Comment: Do you want the sum of all values in all subarrays? Or the actual subarrays themselves (that will be more costly than O(n))?

Comment: Are the sub arrays given and you want to find their sums or do you have to generate the sub arrays from a 1D array first and find their sums?

Comment: thanks for all of the comments I have edited the answer a bit to give an example for an input -> output let me know if you need more information. not 0(n) is fine but I am looking for lower complexity and trying to understand this problem.

Comment: There are O(n^2) subarrays. Any algorithm based on explicitly going over all subarrays can never be more efficient than O(n^2). That's usually not good enough.

Comment: The number of subarrays is n+(n-1)+...+1, which is roughly n^2/2. If you want all the actual subarrays, that means you will have to make O(n^2) memory operations.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the kadane's algorithm, it is for getting the maximum sum of subarrays, which is inherently different problem as yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly simple to do: https://jsfiddle.net/j1LuvxLq/

All you do is iterate possible lenghts and starting points and just print out the subsets. Complexity is O(n²) where n is the length of the original array. No way to improve it thought because that's the order of how many subsets there are.

```
var set = [3, 3, 9, 9, 5].join('')

var set_length = set.length

var subsets = []

for (var length_of_subset = 1; length_of_subset <= set_length; length_of_subset++) {
    for (var start_of_subset = 0; start_of_subset <= set_length - length_of_subset; start_of_subset++) {
        var current_subset = set.substring(start_of_subset, start_of_subset + length_of_subset)
        if(subsets.indexOf(current_subset) == -1) {
            subsets.push(current_subset.split(''))
        }
    }
}

// print the subsets out
for (s in subsets) {
    $('body').append(subsets[s].join(', ') + '<br>')
}
```

Alternative, possibly nicer solution would be to use dynamic programming. Start with 3 and either remove last element or add next element. Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/p82fcs4m/

```
var set = [3, 3, 9, 9, 5].join('')
var subsets = []

take(set[0], set.substring(1))

function take(chosen, left) {

    if(subsets.indexOf(chosen) != -1) {
        return
    }

    subsets.push(chosen)

    if (chosen.length > 1) {
        take(chosen.substring(1), left)
    }

    if (left.length > 0) {
        take(chosen.concat(left[0]), left.substring(1))
    }
}

$('body').append(subsets.join('<br>'))
```

Comment: When I run the for loop solution for input array [1,2,3,4,5,6] I don't get the subsets [1,3] [1,4] [1,5] [1,6] [2,4], [2,5], [2,6] [3,5], [3,6] [4,6] and so on...I haven't got any in depth solution yet so just point this out so that others don't blindly copy paste the code hoping it would find all the sub arrays from a given array.

Answer (score 4):

I had done a work previously to calculate all combinations of amino acids total molecular weight. If you neglect the empty one you should have 2^n - 1 sub arrays. So there is no O(n) here. I've got two methods as binary and recursive.

```js
function getSubArrays(arr){
  var len = arr.length,
     subs = Array(Math.pow(2,len)).fill();
  return subs.map((_,i) => { var j = -1,
                                 k = i,
                               res = [];
                             while (++j < len ) {
                               k & 1 && res.push(arr[j]);
                               k = k >> 1;
                             }
                             return res;
                           }).slice(1);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getSubArrays([1,2,3,4,5])));
```

```js
function getSubArrays(arr){
  if (arr.length === 1) return [arr];
  else {
   subarr = getSubArrays(arr.slice(1));
   return subarr.concat(subarr.map(e => e.concat(arr[0])), [[arr[0]]]);
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getSubArrays([1,2,3,4,5])));
```

I couldn't manage to get subarrays of an array with more than 23 items though.
Here are the performances. To be on the safe side i try with 22 items, first with recursive and then with binary route.

```js
function getSubArrays(arr){
  if (arr.length === 1) return [arr];
  else {
   subarr = getSubArrays(arr.slice(1));
   return subarr.concat(subarr.map(e => e.concat(arr[0])), [[arr[0]]]);
  }
}


var aminos = Array(22).fill().map((_,i) => i+1),
   subarrs = [],
        ps = 0,
        pe = 0;
ps = performance.now();
subarrs = getSubArrays(aminos);
pe = performance.now();
console.log("recursive route took: " + (pe-ps) + "msec to produce " + subarrs.length + " sub arrays");
```

```js
function getSubArrays(arr){
  var len = arr.length,
     subs = Array(Math.pow(2,len)).fill();
  return subs.map((_,i) => { var j = -1,
                                 k = i,
                               res = [];
                             while (++j < len ) {
                               k & 1 && res.push(arr[j]);
                               k = k >> 1;
                             }
                             return res;
                           }).slice(1);
}

var aminos = Array(22).fill().map((_,i) => i+1),
   subarrs = [],
        ps = 0,
        pe = 0;
ps = performance.now();
subarrs = getSubArrays(aminos);
pe = performance.now();
console.log("binary route took: " + (pe-ps) + "msec to produce " + subarrs.length + " sub arrays");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function getSubArrays(arr) {
  const subArrays = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - i; j++) {
      const subArray = arr.slice(i, j + i + 1);
      subArrays.push(subArray);
    }
  }
}
```

Still O(n²) tho

Comment: This is not substantively different from [Elad Becker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64482131), and it shares the same flaw.

Answer (score -1):

I believe using Array.slice is the most clean way to do it, isn't it?

```
function getSubArrays(arr) {
    const subArrays = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            subArrays.push(arr.slice(i, j + 1));
        }
    }
    return subArrays;
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm fails to find `[1, 2, 4]` subarray from `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.